# How to make simple 3 step checkout section like quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello and have a nice day!

I want to create simple step by step element with back button.

I have a next markup

```
<div class="checkout">
    <div class="checkout-step">
        <div class="content">This is step 1</div>
        <div class="button-prev-step">Previous step</div>
        <div class="button-next-step">Next step</div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkout-step">
        <div class="content">This is step 2</div>
        <div class="button-prev-step">Previous step</div>
        <div class="button-next-step">Next step</div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkout-step">
        <div class="content">This is step 3</div>
        <div class="button-prev-step">Previous step</div>
        <div class="button-next-step">Next step</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS (It's not fully complete code, just part of existing code, I don't fully understand how I can do it)

```
var checkoutStepCounter = 0;
var checkoutStepLength = $('.checkout-step').length;
$('.button-next-step').click(function() {
    checkoutStepCounter++;
    if( checkoutStepLength < checkoutStepCounter ) {
        $(this).find('.checkout-step').hide();
        $(this).find('.checkout-step').next('.checkout-step').show();
    }
});
$('.button-prev-step').click(function() {
    checkoutStepCounter--;
    if( checkoutStepLength < checkoutStepCounter ) {
        $(this).find('.checkout-step').hide();
        $(this).find('.checkout-step').prev('.checkout-step').show();
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.button-prev-step, .button-next-step {  display: block; width: 100px; height: 20px; background: red; cursor: pointer; }
.checkout-step { display: none; }
```

https://codepen.io/Frunky/pen/yKNMOM

How to make function `nextStep` and `prevStep`? in result I want to slide between the sections, and in total - send filled data to backend. Now I need to add an ability to slide between `.checkout-step` blocks. May be I need to add simple slider? like slick or owl, but I don't know if it's right way or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple code snippet to show you next and previous button working. You can do some more research and add your desired animation (slide, fade etc.) as per your requirements.

```js
var checkoutSteps = 3;
var currentStep = 1;

$('.button-next-step').click(function() {
    if(currentStep < checkoutSteps){
    $(".checkout-step-"+currentStep+"").hide();
    currentStep++;
    $(".checkout-step-"+currentStep+"").show();
    }
});
$('.button-prev-step').click(function() {
    if(currentStep > 1){
    $(".checkout-step-"+currentStep+"").hide();
    currentStep--;
    $(".checkout-step-"+currentStep+"").show();
    }
});
```

```css
.button-prev-step, .button-next-step {  display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 20px; background: red; cursor: pointer; }
.checkout-step { 
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid #000;
display: none; 
}
.checkout-step-1{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkout">
    <div class="checkout-step checkout-step-1">
        <div class="content">This is step 1</div>
        <div class="button-prev-step">Previous step</div>
        <div class="button-next-step">Next step</div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkout-step checkout-step-2">
        <div class="content">This is step 2</div>
        <div class="button-prev-step">Previous step</div>
        <div class="button-next-step">Next step</div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkout-step checkout-step-3">
        <div class="content">This is step 3</div>
        <div class="button-prev-step">Previous step</div>
        <div class="button-next-step">Next step</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps